# Using Custom AutoCompleteTextView in Android Causes Error

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I extended `AutoCompleteTextView` in android. When I use that new custom `AutoCompleteTextView`  in my XML layout file, Eclipse shows an error saying:

> You must specify a valid content view by calling setContentView() before attempting to show the popup. Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log"`.

Edited XML File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.mypackage.MyAutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/countries_list_custom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:completionHint="Test">
<requestFocus />
</com.mypackage.MyAutoCompleteTextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

By simply taking out my custom view from the XML, the layout shows just fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.